# How to set default value in ng-options multiple using (key value)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

how to set default value in select multiple='multiple' using ng-option ?
I have been trying two ways, please find the code below:

```js
angular.module('ngrepeatSelect', []).controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
 $scope.o1 = {"de":"Deutsch",
 "en":"English","es":"Español",
 "fl":"Flemish","fr":"Français",
 "it":"Italiano","nl":"Nederlands",
 "pl":"Polski",
 "pt":"Português",
 "ro":"Română",
 "tr":"Türkçe"};
 $scope.o2 = {
  "it":{"prefix":"it","label":"Italiano"},
  "fr":{"prefix":"fr","label":"Français"},
  "es":{"prefix":"es","label":"Español"},
  "fl":{"prefix":"fl","label":"Flamand"},
  "en":{"prefix":"en","label":"English"},
  "de":{"prefix":"de","label":"Deutsch"},
  "pt":{"prefix":"pt","label":"Português"},
  "ro":{"prefix":"ro","label":"Română"},"pl":{"prefix":"pl","label":"Polski"},
  "tr":{"prefix":"tr","label":"Türkçe"},
  "nl":{"prefix":"nl","label":"Nederlands"}};
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="ngrepeatSelect">
 <div ng-controller="ExampleController">
  <div>
   <select
     ng-init="selected1 = 'fr'"
     multiple="multiple"
     ng-model="selected1"
     ng-options="key as value for (key, value) in o1 track by key">
   </select>
   <select
     ng-init="selected2 = 'fr'"
     multiple="multiple"
     ng-model="selected2"
     ng-options="language.prefix as language.label for language in o2 track by language.prefix">
   </select>
  </div>
  <div>
   -{{selected1}}-
   -{{selected2}}-
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

For instance, how to preselect 'de', 'fr' and 'ro' for each of the two selects?
Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried `ng-selected` ?

Comment: Not really, but I will, thank you. However, Slava.K found out the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just prepopulate `selected1` in your controller. Also it seems like`track by key` is obsolete and can be removed. Find the working snippet below:

```js
angular.module('ngrepeatSelect', []).controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
   $scope.selected1 = ["de", "fr", "ro"];
 
   $scope.o1 = {"de":"Deutsch",
 "en":"English","es":"Español",
 "fl":"Flemish","fr":"Français",
 "it":"Italiano","nl":"Nederlands",
 "pl":"Polski",
 "pt":"Português",
 "ro":"Română",
 "tr":"Türkçe"};
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="ngrepeatSelect">
  <div ng-controller="ExampleController">
    <div>
 <select
   multiple="multiple"
   ng-model="selected1"
   ng-options="key as value for (key, value) in o1">
 </select>
    </div>
    <div>
      -{{selected1}}-
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```